# Google Cloud SQL very slow on server

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, cloud

I have an issue that is driving me mad. Developing locally in Eclipse, I have no issues connecting to Google Cloud SQL in my locally running appengine and in mySql Workbench.

However, after deployment jsp pages and servlets that access the database takes 30 - 50 seconds to load. Note that I locally connect to the Google Cloud SQL and not a local instance of SQL.

The most simple code I run is this (it takes more than 30 seconds to process):

```
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS);
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER, PASSWORD);
{catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}

Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    String query = "select * from myTable";
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

while (rs.nexy()){

//iterate and output
}
```

It is with con = (Connection) DriverManager ... that the process slows down. I have tried "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver" and "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". I have tried connecting via IP and with URL = jdbc:google:mysql://[dbinstance]/OUTDATABASE?user=USER.

Things work splendidly locally (connection to cloud sql) but not when deployed to app engine. And it's driving me mad.

I will appreciate any help.

Kind regards.

Comment: I'm having the exactly same problem for python. What is your sql instance region? It seems this is a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=197
I haven't get response from google yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're noticing a slowdown for the first time a Java resource is loaded you may want look at your `appengine-web.xml` configuration file and ensure `<precompilation-enabled>true</precompilation-enabled>`
Perhaps your JSP's are being compiled for the first time.

If not you'll have to do some more profiling to figure out where the delay is.